# django set multiply function for single url

Tags: python, django

There is 2 functions in views.py, (cellphone and datetime).

views.py:

```
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import pymysql


def cellphone(request):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    url ='http://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-95906/Huawei-Mate-S-Dual-SIM-64GB-Mobile-Phone/'
    data = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    price =  soup.body.find('span', attrs={'id':'frmLblPayablePriceAmount'}).text

    return render(request, 'system.html', {'price': price})



def datetime(request):
    import datetime
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'system.html', {'now': now})
```

system.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #3A3F44;
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body>
    <div style="height: 50px;background:#16A085;">
        * {{ price }} * {{ now }} *
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Here because the cellphone function function has been set for *system* url, the datetime function won't works.)

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from system.views import cellphone, datetime

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^system/', cellphone),
    url(r'^system/', datetime),
```

I want when the page is loaded, both function works and I see the price and datetime on the screen. How it is possible?

=========================================================

Is it possible to do this?

I created `datetime.html` file:

```
<b> {{ now }} </b>
```

And then changed only this part

```
return render(request, 'datetime.html', {'now': now})
```

from views.py.
Next changed system.html like this:

```
* {{ price }} * {% include 'datetime.html' %} *
```

But what can I do next? What kind of changes I can do in urls.py?
Does it work? Both separate functions work in a single web page with one URL address, right?!

Comment: which version of django are you using ?

Comment: Django Version: 1.8.2 and Python Version:  3.4.3

Comment: you need to do one view that gives you both values, one request leads to a single view. Just add 'now':datetime.now() to the context in the cellphone view.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour, only the cellphone is used due to being the first in the list, maybe you have some middle ware that sets the value of `now`

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you are using [The built in now filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#now) to print the current time and date and are mistaking it for the context variable.

You cannot have two views respond to a single request, that's not how django works. You have to make a single view that pulls all the data the template needs and renders it to a response. You can still have separate functions to derive the context and then just collect them in the view.

Comment: Well let me explain what I'm looking for. I want to create a single-web page website ( a simple website with only a single page and single url that must be `/system`. Each function must be set to different url to work, so do I have to define many urls? And it means I have to type different urls for different process?

Comment: @niloofar you can use one function for all your processes or use class based views to manage your different processes easily for an example see Ziya's answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would do something with the date time, you can store the time in datebase in you cellphone function.

views.py

```
import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen

import pymysql
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def cellphone(request):
    url ='http://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-95906/Huawei-Mate-S-Dual-SIM-64GB-Mobile-Phone/'
    data = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    price =  soup.body.find('span', attrs={'id':'frmLblPayablePriceAmount'}).text
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    return render(request, 'system.html', {'price': price, 'now': now})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from system.views import cellphone

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^system/$', cellphone),  # Django would only call the first match.
                                   # And the '$' at the end of regex is important.
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to load small parts of your webpage while using only one webpage.

You can use one URL per subset but you will need to use javascript/jQuery something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datetime_content").load("/system/datetime");
});
```

with this in your datetime function (same template as in your question)

```
return render(request, 'datetime.html', {'now': now})
```

and this in the url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^system/', cellphone),
    url(r'^system/datetime', datetime),
]
```

you can of course do the same with the `cellphone` function/view

but I would still recommend class based views: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/

more on ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info